# How to combine a list and data.frame in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list named `data3`, like this (from JSON file).

```
data3 <- list(structure(c(14, 7, 10, 4, 7), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(16, 10, 12, 6, 7), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(77708, 39434, 45489, 30223, 34829 ), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(9828, 6855, 7967, 5638, 6263), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(7626, 5783, 6406, 5074, 5348), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(1012, 404, 546, 251, 300), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")))
```

and it has some missing values like

```
 data3[4]
[[1]]
   0    3    2   14    7 
9828 6855 7967 5638 6263 

> data3[400]
[[1]]
 0  3  2 
44 35 38
```

And I have a data.frame named `data1`, like this:

```
       date  d1     d2  d3               d4
 3 20150402   4   5693   0              NEW             
 4 20150402   4   5693   0     UPGRADE(OEM)    
 5 20150402   4   5693   0  UPGRADE(ONLINE) 
 ...
```

I need to combine them like

```
    date  d1    d2  d3   d4     0     2     3     7    14
20150402   4  5693   0  NEW 77708 39434 45489 30223 34829
```

The problem is that not all of `data3` has the same number of elements.

I have tried this:

```
aaa <- NULL
for (i in 1:482){
  aaa <- cbind(data1[i, ],data3[[i]])
}
```

but it didn't work.
May be there is another way to do this but I have no idea.

Comment: list(structure(c(14, 7, 10, 4, 7), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", 
"14", "7")), structure(c(16, 10, 12, 6, 7), .Names = c("0", "3", 
"2", "14", "7")), structure(c(77708, 39434, 45489, 30223, 34829
), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(9828, 6855, 
7967, 5638, 6263), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(7626, 
5783, 6406, 5074, 5348), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), 
    structure(c(1012, 404, 546, 251, 300), .Names = c("0", "3", 
    "2", "14", "7")))  there is a problem is that not all of data3 has the same amount of elements.

Comment: eg: `data3[4]
[[1]]
   0    3    2   14    7 
9828 6855 7967 5638 6263 

> data3[480]
[[1]]
 0 
30`

Comment: Please, edit your OP to include the data. I forgot a part on my previous comment. Try `do.call(rbind,lapply(data3,function(x) setNames(x[c("0","2","3","7","14")],c("0","2","3","7","14") )))` and this will produce a `matrix` which you can `cbind` to `data1`,

Comment: Welcome to SO. I included the dput of the list directly into the question. I also edited the title to include the data.frame instead of a matrix. And I have tried to clarify the question.

Comment: Thank you all guys. But the problem wasn't solved. I added some example lines of data3 in order to clarify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your `data1` data.frame so I am posting an example that uses first 6 rows of popular `iris` dataset:

```
> data3 <- list(structure(c(14, 7, 10, 4, 7), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(16, 10, 12, 6, 7), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(77708, 39434, 45489, 30223, 34829 ), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(9828, 6855, 7967, 5638, 6263), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(7626, 5783, 6406, 5074, 5348), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")), structure(c(1012, 404, 546, 251, 300), .Names = c("0", "3", "2", "14", "7")))
> 
> 
> t(as.data.frame(data3)) -> x
> rownames(x) <- NULL
> x
         0     3     2    14     7
[1,]    14     7    10     4     7
[2,]    16    10    12     6     7
[3,] 77708 39434 45489 30223 34829
[4,]  9828  6855  7967  5638  6263
[5,]  7626  5783  6406  5074  5348
[6,]  1012   404   546   251   300
> cbind(iris[1:6,],x)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species     0     3     2    14     7
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    14     7    10     4     7
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    16    10    12     6     7
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 77708 39434 45489 30223 34829
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  9828  6855  7967  5638  6263
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  7626  5783  6406  5074  5348
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  1012   404   546   251   300
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It throws an error  due to not all of data3 has the same numbers of elements.  For instance, `data3[4] [[1]] 0 3 2 14 7 9828 6855 7967 5638 6263`       `data3[480] [[1]] 0 30`